# Searching for courses in OpenEdX

Tags: openedx

I'm using the Open EdX courses API (/courses/v1/courses/) to list courses. This works fine. I noticed that this endpoint supports a "search_term" query parameter that is not very well documented. Can I search for courses that contains a specific search term in a specific field (like short_description) perhaps by specifying an Elasticsearch query string?  Or does this just search various text fields for the search term?